# failed upgrade magento 1.5x to 1.6x

Tags: magento, cpanel, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, mage

i've tried upgrade my magento 1.5x to magento 1.6x in my cpanel, but i always find "failed..failed..and failed". i've tried this way..:

find . -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*

chmod 550 ./mage

then after that when i tried this..:

./mage mage-setup .

the result is failed, this is the messages..:

Running initial setup...

XCache requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
The Zend Engine API version 220090626 which is installed, is newer.
Contact mOo at http://xcache.lighttpd.net for a later version of XCache.

Failed loading /usr/lib/kloxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so:  /usr/lib/kl                                                                                        oxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so: cannot open shared object file: No suc                                                                                        h file or directory
Cannot load Zend Extension Manager - it was built with configuration 1.2.0, wher                                                                                        eas running engine is API220090626,NTS
XCache requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
The Zend Engine API version 220090626 which is installed, is newer.
Contact mOo at http://xcache.lighttpd.net for a later version of XCache.

Failed loading /usr/lib/kloxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so:  /usr/lib/kl                                                                                        oxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so: cannot open shared object file: No suc                                                                                        h file or directory
Cannot load Zend Extension Manager - it was built with configuration 1.2.0, wher                                                                                        eas running engine is API220090626,NTS
XCache requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
The Zend Engine API version 220090626 which is installed, is newer.
Contact mOo at http://xcache.lighttpd.net for a later version of XCache.

Failed loading /usr/lib/kloxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so:  /usr/lib/kloxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load Zend Extension Manager - it was built with configuration 1.2.0, whereas running engine is API220090626,NTS

what is it? can you help me guys to fix my problem? I really need your helps guys! thank's!

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing to do with Magento, that's a server setup issue. Have you rebuilt apache/php using EasyApache by any chance?

It looks like you have incompatible version of PHP and XCache.

You should ask your host for assistance, it's not a Magento issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your website works fine and you have got problem in the command line, it may be wrong *php* configuration. Try to update `php.ini` or edit the `./mage` - enter valid php binary path.

Comment: "Try to update php.ini or edit the ./mage - enter valid php binary path", can u give me clearer explanation?

Comment: Your web server uses different php than comand line. Use `phpinfo()` and `php -i` to determine *Loaded Configuration File*